# Replace the whole content of a file using Ansible

Tags: scripting, ansible, yaml

I would like to be able to replace the whole content of a file using Ansible playbook.

I have written that piece of code already but it seems the use of the wildcard is wrong way to go.

```
---
  - hosts: my_hosts
    tasks:
     - name: Replace the content of my file
       lineinfile:
         path: /home/user-ansible/test/conf
         regexp: "*"
         line: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/ansible/config/conf') }}"
```

Answer (score 7):

To replace the content of a file on the target server (`dest`) and make sure it is always aligned with your source (`src`), use the [`copy` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html)

```
---
- name: Demo play to copy file
  hosts: my_hosts
  tasks:
  - name: Replace the content of my file
    copy:
      src: /home/user-ansible/test/conf
      dest: /home/ansible/config/conf
```

Additional note: There are yaml indentation issues in the playbook you posted that might cause problems in the future. Please [take Y minutes to learn yaml](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/) and pay attention to indentation and new lines. You can validate your playbooks with [yamllint](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [ansible-lint](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-lint/) prior to posting

Comment: Ok thank you for this. I don't why I was so complicated with it. By the way thank you for the tip - I didn't know yamllint for instance which found some errors in your code though. I will try to work it out. Thank you anyway.